# VANET: How to Implement A* Routing Algorithm in SUMO Simulation with Existing Configuration, Network, Trips, and Routing Files for research purpose?

Tags: simulation, sumo, vehicle-routing, mobility, ad-hoc-network

I'm working on a PhD research topic involving SUMO (Simulation of Urban MObility), and I'm trying to integrate the A* algorithm into my existing simulation. I have the following files:

- **my_simulation.sumocfg**: SUMO configuration file.
- **my_network.net.xml.gz**: SUMO network file.
- **my_trips.trips.xml**: SUMO trips file.
- **my_routing.rou.xml**: SUMO routing file.

My goal is to utilize the A* algorithm to improve route planning within this simulation. However, I'm facing challenges in integrating A* with my existing setup. Here are some specific points I need guidance on:

1. How can I integrate the A* algorithm with my existing SUMO simulation using the provided files? What steps are involved in this integration process?
2. How do I extract relevant data from my SUMO configuration, network, trips, and routing files to use as inputs for the A* algorithm?
3. Do you have any code examples or snippets that demonstrate how to implement the A* algorithm within the SUMO environment? Specifically, how to compute optimal routes and apply them to vehicles?

I'm open to any suggestions, code samples, or step-by-step instructions to help me get started with implementing A* in my existing SUMO simulation. Thank you!

`

Comment: Just as a general comment. SUMO already has A* implemented so there is no point to doing that again. You can even load custom edge weights and use the routing algorithm. https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Routing.html